# Need java equivalent SHA512 for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

as I'm only a beginner in this field this question may seem to be very trivial, but I beg your pardon. I've a Java code as follows:

```
String passwordSalt = "somesalt";
       byte[] bsalt = base64ToByte(passwordSalt);
       byte[] thePasswordToDigestAsBytes = ("somepassword").getBytes("UTF-8");
       System.out.println("------------------------------"+passwordSalt);
       MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(bsalt);
        byte[] input = digest.digest(thePasswordToDigestAsBytes);
        System.out.println("------------------------------"+byteToBase64(input));
```

I want to achieve the same in Objective-C and I'm using the following code :

```
NSData *saltdata = [Base64 decode:@"some base64 encoded salt"];
NSString *passwordDgst;
passwordDgst = @"somepassword";
NSData *input = [passwordDgst dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512_CTX context;
    CC_SHA512_Init(&context);
    CC_SHA512_Update(&context, [saltdata bytes], (CC_LONG)[saltdata length]);
    CC_SHA512_Update(&context, [input bytes], (CC_LONG)[input length]);
    CC_SHA512_Final(hash, &context);
    input = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:(const void *)hash    length:sizeof(unsigned char)*CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    passwordDgst = [input encodeBase64WithNewlines:NO];
```

But this seems to generate a different hash than the Java Code? Why is that? Can anybody clarify me that? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9629529/971401).